# Is there a way to execute a .exe CGI application on Linux + Apache

Tags: linux, apache, cgi

I have to migrate a web server from Windows + IIS to Linux + Apache, but there are some webpages rely on .exe CGI applications (some financial calculators) to generate the outputs. Is there an easy way to get this job done?

BTW, I don't have the access to the source code of those .exe file. Even though I have, it would take a long time to re-code them in PHP or other languages.

Edit: OK. I make my question more detailed. There is a form in a webpage whose action points to a .exe file. When the form is submitted, the .exe file generates results based on the HTTP GET data. The results that should have outputted to console are captured by the webserver to generate html.

Wine can do that job? I just googled but cannot find the solution.

Comment: how could recoding (to PHP) a code that just creates static HTML from the form output take long?

Comment: Thanks all! 
They don't just create static HTML. They receive data from HTTP GET, and perform the calculation and output the results. There are more than ten calculators and I don't have the financial knowledge. So I looked for a better way to get this job done. But now I am really concerning about the security issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Fantastic! Wine did did the job perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Wine on the Linux server. Wine can execute .exe files on the commandline. See http://ftp.winehq.org/pub/wine/docs/en/wineusr-guide.html#RUNNING-WINE .

On the webserver, you can then use CGI or PHP to execute the command.

Note that this may be very messy, and may have serious security or performance issues if you aren't careful.